# Listview will not render in column

Tags: flutter, dart

This code crashes when run and won't render the Listview or the textfield:

```
return Scaffold(

        floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
            child : Icon(Icons.add, color : Colors.white),
            onPressed : () async {
              contactsModel.entityBeingEdited = Contact();
              contactsModel.setStackIndex(1);
            }
        ),
        body :
       Column( children: <Widget> [
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
           child:
           TextField(
             controller: searchController,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                 hintText: "search text",
                 border: OutlineInputBorder()
             ), //decoration
           ), //textfield
         ), // padding
         Expanded(
           child:
         ListView.builder(
          itemCount : contactsModel.entityList.length,
          itemBuilder : (BuildContext inBuildContext, int inIndex) {
            Contact contact = contactsModel.entityList[inIndex];
            return Column(
              children : [
                Slidable(
                  delegate : SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                  actionExtentRatio : .25,
                  child : ListTile(
                    title : Text("${contact.name}"),
                    subtitle : contact.pwordHint == null ? null : Text("${contact.pwordHint} - ${contact.notes}"),
                    // Edit existing contact.
                    onTap : () async {
                      // Get the data from the database and send to the edit view.
                      contactsModel.entityBeingEdited = await ContactsDBWorker.db.get(contact.id);
                      contactsModel.setStackIndex(1);
                    }
                  ),
                  secondaryActions : [
                    IconSlideAction(
                      caption : "Delete",
                      color : Colors.red,
                      icon : Icons.delete,
                      onTap : () => _deleteContact(inContext, contact)
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                Divider()
              ]
            ); /* End Column. */
          } /* End itemBuilder. */
        ), /* End ListView.builder. */
         ),
        ],
       ),
      ); /* End Scaffold. */
```

Error:

> Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Comment: "This code crashes when run and won't render " You should post the error message from the debug console

Comment: Sorry I was posting for a particular user. I've edited the question

Comment: Your code seems OK, the entire problem lies inside `Slideable`. Can you post its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your Slideable inside `SizedBox` like this.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 100, 
  child: Slideable(...),
)
```